# http request return value not getting all data flutter

Tags: http, flutter, dart

I am working with http request. suddenly on my request, i was getting response status code as "200" so that my api is working.. but, upon my response body that return is incomplete. by the way, this is my resources used.

```
  String APILink = "http://10.12.50.46:9191";
  String compressedString2;

 Future<SuccessData> getSession() async {
        http.Response response2=await http.post(
          Uri.encodeFull(APILink+"/Mobile/StartSession"),
          headers:{
            "Auth-Key":"InSys-dev-key-001 ",
          },body:compressedString2,
        );
        print("Compressed JSON:"+compressedString2);
        print(response2.statusCode);
      var dataGather2 = json.decode(response2.body);
      print(response2.body);
    }
```

this is my actual responseupon using insomnia (Rest API)

[image]

and here is my print data upon my logcat:

[image]

if you notice, my return data upon "ResultSet" is not complete.. also the other data do be fetch like status, errormsg,and tag is not viewed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Print function will not print everything 
You can see **print() statements in Flutter are truncated in flutter run output**
 https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/22665

Solution 1: 
From https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/22665#issuecomment-580613192 
You can use the following two code snippet

```
void logLongString(String s) {
    if (s == null || s.length <= 0) return;
    const int n = 1000;
    int startIndex = 0;
    int endIndex = n;
    while (startIndex < s.length) {
      if (endIndex > s.length) endIndex = s.length;
      print(s.substring(startIndex, endIndex));
      startIndex += n;
      endIndex = startIndex + n;
    }
}
```

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/22665#issuecomment-513476234

```
void printWrapped(String text) {
  final pattern = new RegExp('.{1,800}'); // 800 is the size of each chunk
  pattern.allMatches(text).forEach((match) => print(match.group(0)));
}
```

Solution 2:
In Android Studio Debug mode, set break point and copy variable content in Variables window
[image]